# iOS 6 Facebook, Twttier UIActionSheet class

Tags: iphone, ios6

I've used it before (as a demo thing) but I can't find the code.

I'm just trying to find the name of the class that presents the iOS6 action sheet with the image buttons for things like Twitter, Facebook, Email and so on.

Please could you let me know what the class is.  I know it isn't a standard `UIActionSheet` but can't think of the name.

For an example see the photos app.  Go into a photo and click the "share" button.  That's the sheet I'm looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!  Trawling through my BitBucket commits and found it.

It is...

```
UIActivityViewController
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html